# How to generate the form for a Geo custom type in Phoenix

Tags: forms, elixir, phoenix-framework, geo

On my Elixir / Phoenix app I have an `Address` model that has a `location` field on it.

The field is a [Geo.Geometry](https://github.com/bryanjos/geo/blob/master/lib/geo/geometry.ex) custom type from the [Geo](https://github.com/bryanjos/geo) library, with the following structure:

```
%Geo.Point{coordinates: {30, -90}, srid: 4326}
```

I am looking for a way to generate a form for my `Address` model that includes this `location`, but I'm not sure what's the proper way to do this.

I was thinking about adding virtual fields to my `Address` model, like `lat` and `lng`, use them in the form and then "translate" those fields into a `%Geo.Point` in the `Address.changeset` function.

Is that the right way to go, or is there a more straightforward solution? And if so, how to do this in the changeset?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 3):

The method I had suggested has finally worked: adding `lat` and `lng` virtual fields to the `Address` model and then setting the value of my `location` field in the `Address` changeset with `put_changes`.

Comment: That is exactly the usecase for virtual fields, so +1 to this solution.

Answer (score 3):

**Should avoid polluting schema with UI requirements.** I strongly recommend reading José Valim post explaining the schemaless queries.

http://blog.plataformatec.com.br/2016/05/ectos-insert_all-and-schemaless-queries/

Hope it helps.